# Angular.json config to exclude a script file to generate the source map

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, source-maps

So working with an angular cli 8 I stumble into a necessity where I need to load an external resource as part of the scripts like:

```
...,
{
   scripts: [ "path/to/script.min.js" ]
}
```

This file is already minified and has it's own source map, I want to reference it with it's own source map and avoid the cli process do this again, sinde it's causing double source mapping and not showing the actual source map build for the file.

I tried to source-map { scritps: false } but this will means that none of my scripts file will create a source maps.

In resume, I want to avoid creating source maps for this file since I want to debug it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is any way to to this using angular config (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11305). You could just add your script in the `index.html` file, but then that'll mean one more request to display the page.

Comment: Thanks @David, I endded up doing that, taking that in consideration (making one more call)